# Java intercept own process stdout and stderr streams

Tags: java, logging, stream, stdout, stderr

In Java, I want to intercept my process's `stdout` and `stderr`. I don't want to prevent it from going to the console/default destination eventually, but at every newline, I need to copy that line into my own log file (with some formatting and HTMLification). The only way I can see to do this is [something like this](http://sysgears.com/articles/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-writing-to-a-log4j-appender/) -- which might work, but I'm worried about different charsets, want to eventually format output the same way as before instead of suppressing it, and I need to handle it at every newline, not when it feels like flushing (even with auto-flush = true).

Is there a library of some sort that makes this easier?

Answer (score 0):

> but at every newline, I need to copy that line into my own log file (with some formatting and HTMLification).

Why don't you consider the classic Unix utility `tee`? A demo:

1. `tail -f source | tee tee.sink`
2. `echo "foo" >> source` -- you should see "foo" also on your terminal
3. `cat tee.sink` should display `foo`.

Or did I misunderstand what you want?

Comment: I need to do this inside the Java process.